# Want to join the column of one table to another table and i don't have any common field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 31 rows:

```
 1718
  548
  ..
```

another table with 31 rows:

```
  date    | value
----------+-----------
 20180924 | Cellsgold
 20180924 | Sitegold
..
```

I want get result set as

```
row 1 of table 1 | row 1 of table 2
row 2 of table 1 | row 2 of table 2
```

No sorting is required, I just want to have both columns in front of each other .

31 rows in-front of table 2's 31 rows

like

```
1718 | 20180924 | Cellsgold
 548 | 20180924 | Sitegold
```

Comment: You need to give us some column from each table which can be used to generate the order which you presented above.  Otherwise, your question is not well-founded.

Comment: The problem is that while it may present the rows in one order today, they might come back in a different order tomorrow. SQL databases have no implied ordering even though the evidence of your queries might suggest otherwise. As @TimBiegeleisen says you absolutely must have something to order by. With that its an easy question using row_number(). Other thing you can do is add a rowid (make it an identity column) so that you will always get a fixed order that will never change.

Comment: Can you share the schema of both the tables?

Comment: Table 2 is a static table where date is changed daily..table 1 has values which will be in same order daily @TomC..

Comment: If you need an order, add an identity key. Otherwise the order you get them back will not be guaranteed to be the same as the order you right them. Order just does not exist in a sql database.

Comment: It is always advisable to include a unique key/primary key for a table which will simplify ordering / joining  etc

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You can combine the rows, so you get one value from each table.  But you cannot control which rows match -- unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned, not imposing an order with `ORDER BY` will produce unpredictable results.

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER () AS rn, *
      FROM table1) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT row_number() OVER () AS rn, *
      FROM table2) AS t2
USING (rn);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is/are only 31 rows each

DB is not recommended(as rownum may change every time)

it's better to use excel/calc with concatenate function